# Make inputs from console expandable

Tags: python, shell, input

Assume this short shell script

```
#! /bin/sh                                                                      
read -p "Enter directory: " dir
echo $dir
```

or python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
dir = input("Enter directory: ")
print dir
```

When I try to input the directory from the console using environmental variables, e.g. `$PROJECT`

```
$PROJECT/src
```

the environmental variable is not expanded but <kbd>TAB</kbd> appears as a TAB instead.

Is there a way to make inputs from console expandable?

Comment: The code that `input` executes is part of the Python executable. They probably did not want `input` to *always* expand a tab to a file name (imagine you are using it to input a list of names. Also, it's not even a standard function for all consoles). I don't know what `read` does.

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use `sys.argv`?You can pass the environmental variable as a parameter to your script. For example; assume the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python           
import sys                                                

print sys.argv
```

When we run it as the following:

```
python2 example.py $PROJECT_PATH
```

You will find the `$PROJECT_PATH` as the second element in `sys.argv` list. It will exactly look like the following output when running the above command:

```
['example.py', '/path/to/example/project']
```